# VS 2019 CMake looking for file it is not supposed to

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I run into a problem when building a Cmake Project with CmakeLists.txt in VS 2019.
It tells me this:[image]

What I did before the error:

- I created a tests folder
- I created a test.cpp file
- A Pop up window opened from Cmake -> asking if I want to add it automatically to add_executable, I declined it
- I manually added it to the Project Sources with tests/test.cpp
- test got highlighted blue, so I changed the name to sample_test.cpp
- rewrote test.cppp to sample_test.cpp
- build CmakeLists.txt
- error

I hope the provided information is enough otherwise let me know and thanks in advance!

What I tried:

- deleting the cache
- deleting the out file
- deleting CMakeSettings.Json
- repaired VS 2019
- uninstalled CMake and reinstalled
- Added the "ghost" file -> results in same error message
- deleted repo and cloned it in a completely new directory
- deleted .vs file
- reinstalling VS 2019
- deleting VS with InstallCleanup.exe, removed every VS file and reinstalled

Good to know:
On a colleagues machine it build without problems, so on his machine Cmake doesn't look for this file. So the problem seems to be locally on the machine.

Also I do not want this file and folder anymore, I have deleted it and somehow CMake is still looking for it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(team1 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED COMPONENTS common visualization io)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.h mainwindow.ui
    userinterface.h userinterface.cpp
    fileviewer.h fileviewer.cpp
    segmentcreator.h segmentcreator.cpp
    filerepresentation.h filerepresentation.cpp
    filehandler.h filehandler.cpp
    utils/utils.cpp utils/utils.h
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )

else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
    else()
        add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
        )

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})


target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()
```

Comment: You should post code instead of screenshots. Can you post the contents of your cmakelists.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I reinstalled Qt and it worked. I don't know if Qt somehow caches the files that are supposed to be used in a project, but reinstalling it at least made the CMake generate again without errors.
Maybe someone knows more about what Qt does there, I am curious to know.